# How to factor out a variable from an exponential?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I hope this question isn't completely newbish. Lets say you have the equation: $y\sin(x)+y+e^y=x$

$y$ can obviously be factored out as $y(\sin(x)+1)+e^y=x$

But can y also be factored out of the exponential to help make an explicit solution?

Please help me :( I'm melting.

Comment: Is this part of a bigger problem?

Comment: No, but I thought the question would be fairly straightforward; can y be isolated/factored out of an exponential?
Just to make it more clear, I added x on the RHS and so it can be interpreted as _"does this have an explicit solution?"_

Comment: The point of my comment was that often times this sort of situation comes up in problems in which you can't solve for $y$ (or whatever), because you're supposed to use some other tool to solve the problem.I still don't understand what you mean with 'explicit solution' though.

Comment: I don't know what to say D:

I'm trying to put y on one side and everything else on the other. I was wondering if there was any kind of approach to doing so when you have exponentials in the equation regardless of how convoluted the method might be.

Comment: I had misread the expression which led to me not understanding what you wanted. It is unlikely that you can solve for $y$ here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't factor it out of the exponential.  There is a closed-form expression for $y$, but it requires the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$ y = \dfrac{x}{1+\sin(x)} -W \left( {\frac {\exp\left( \frac{x}{1+\sin(x)} \right)}{1+\sin \left( x \right) }} \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Wasn't even aware of the Lambert W function until now. You learn something new everyday.